# LibGDX FitViewport resizes properly, but resets after changing screens

Tags: java, libgdx, viewport, window-resize

I'm having problems with `FitViewport` in LibGDX. When resizing the window, everything works fine. Next I switch screens, and everything just flips back to the normal dimensions and the images get cropped to the left side, while the dimensions of the application remain resized.

After resizing, FitViewport works fine:
[image: Resized window, no problems]

But then, when I press the `to first screen` button, this happens:

[image: Next screen, resizing fails]

So everything works fine (pressing the `to main screen` button takes you back to the original screen), except for the scaling an positioning of the buttons and images.

The dimensions of the window stay the same, but the image gets reverted to its original size (which is 500x500) and put at coords (0,0).

Any ideas or suggestions on how to solve this? I'm breaking my head over this one, can't seem to get it right... I want it to be just like the first screen.

---

These are my class files: I use an abstract Screen class to keep track of the screens (and for expanding later on) and a ScreenManager:

**Main class:**

```
public class MainClass implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        ScreenManager.setScreen(new MainScreen());
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen() != null) {
            ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().render();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        if (ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen() != null)
            ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().resize(width, height);
    }
}
```

**Abstract Screen Class:**

```
public abstract class Screen {

    public abstract void create();

    public abstract void render();

    public abstract void resize(int width, int height);

    public abstract void pause();

    public abstract void dispose();

    public abstract void resume();
}
```

**Screen Manager Class:**

```
public class ScreenManager {

    private static Screen currentScreen;

    public static void setScreen(Screen screen) {
            if (currentScreen != null)
            currentScreen.dispose();
        currentScreen = screen;
        currentScreen.create();
    }

    public static Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return currentScreen;
    }
}
```

**Main Screen Class:**

```
public class MainScreen extends Screen {

    private Texture bg1;
    private Image bg1Image;
    private Skin skin;

    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport fitViewport;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        fitViewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);

        bg1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background1.png"));
        bg1Image = new Image(bg1);
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));

        TextButton nextButton = new TextButton("to first screen", skin);
        nextButton.setPosition(200, 200);
        nextButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ScreenManager.setScreen(new FirstScreen());
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        });

        stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
        stage.addActor(bg1Image);
        stage.addActor(nextButton);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        fitViewport.apply();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        fitViewport.update(width, height, true);
        camera.update();
    }
}
```

**First Screen Class:**

```
public class FirstScreen extends Screen {

    private Texture bg2;
    private Image bg2Image;
    private Skin skin;

    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport fitViewport;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        fitViewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);

        bg2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background2.png"));
        bg2Image = new Image(bg2);
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));

        TextButton prevButton = new TextButton("to main screen", skin);
        prevButton.setPosition(200, 200);
        prevButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ScreenManager.setScreen(new MainScreen());
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        });

        stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
        stage.addActor(bg2Image);
        stage.addActor(prevButton);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        fitViewport.apply();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        fitViewport.update(width, height, true);
        camera.update();
    }
}
```

*(I know I provided a lot of classes, but I wanted to explain everything in detail...)*
I'm guessing it's probably something minor, but I can't seem to get it right and it's driving me nuts...
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is here:

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    fitViewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
```

every single time you are checking current window size and create viewport with such size that window has. The solution is to manually define window size and create new screen viewport due to this value.

Create static public size variables in your **Main class** (you can of course create it enywhere ou want or not create but write values directly - but this is not good due to future refactoring)

```
    public static final float WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600; //or any other values you need
```

then just create your viewport and camera like

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Main.WIDTH, Main.HEIGHT);
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Main.WIDTH, Main.HEIGHT);
    fitViewport = new FitViewport(Main.WIDTH, Main.HEIGHT, camera);
```

that's all.

---

Please also consider not creating new Camera if you won't need this - maybe default **stage** camera is enough for you? Think about it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it :)
You're right, I was adding the wrong window size to the viewport. Seems totally obvious now you said it.

And thanks for the camera tip, I didn't actually need it. A lot easier when I just use the default camera.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `resize` on the newly instantiated screen when you create a new one with your ScreenManager. It works the first time because you are creating the first screen before `resize` is called on your ApplicationListener, which in turn does call `resize` on the screen.

By the way, you also must call `dispose` on these screens before they go out of scope, or you will leak memory. And `dispose` all your assets, batches, etc. (anything implementing Disposable) in the screens' `dispose` methods.

Comment: I tried calling the `resize` method in the `create` method, but without any effect. Where exactly do I have to call `resize` on the screen? I tried different things but without success.

Also, regarding `dispose`, every time a new screen is set the `dispose` method is called on the previous screen, which in turn disposes everything. I just didn't add the `dispose` method to my example.